# Does the order of wires to assign matter?

Tags: verilog

In Verilog, given wires `a` and `b`, is there a difference between:

```
assign a = b;
```

And

```
assign b = a;
```

?

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference in such a case.But what are a & b ?
Example :- What if one of them is a wire which connects some gate input to a driving source ?

Comment: Presmuably you are also going to drive one of those nets from some other source. If you use your first version, then also assign `a` from some other logic, you will probably get a simulation error (or unexpected behavior) due to multiple sources driving `a`.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted so much? It's something I was wondering about too.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it does matter.

`assign a = b;` assigns `a` to get whatever value `b` has, whenever `b` changes.

In simulation, this means if you also have somewhere

```
assign a = c | d & e;
```

Then

1. You'd have a conflict because `a` is assigned in two places.

This could be resolved by declaring the two assignments with different strength settings, for example

```
assign weak a = b;
assign strong a = c & d | e;
```

But this would probably not be synthesizable, at least for FPGA targets.

2. Changes to `c`, `d`, or `e` would have no affect on `b`.

In synthesis, the `assign a=b;` could infer simply that `a` and `b` are the same net, or it could infer a buffer connecting `b` to `a`. Which one is actually produced depends on the whim of your synthesis tool.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have this:

```
reg a;

always @ (posedge clock) begin
    a <= someAmazingSignal;
end
```

Then it would matter. This would be fine:

```
assign b = a; //Assuming that b is of course a wire and not a reg.
```

On the other hand this wouldn't:

```
assign a = b; //Because a is a register and you can't assign to one of those.
```

And wouldn't work even if you had:

```
wire a;
assign a = someAmazingSignal;
```

Because here we have already assigned a to something, so we can't assign b to it.

---

As a side note, without any context it is very difficult to give you an answer. Depending on what `a` is and what `b` is, the answer will be either yes it makes a difference, or no it doesn't.